# Avoid blank page after and before abstract

Tags: page-breaking, abstract

I have blank page before and after each abstract and before each chapter.

I also have two language in my abstract and need the two abstract in the same page.

So I need

- page 1: title
- page 2: the two abstract in different language
- page 3: the index
- page 4: introduction
- page 5: start chapter 1
- page 6: start chapter 2

This is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,final]{book}
    \usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    
    \oddsidemargin=-0cm
    \evensidemargin=0cm
    \topmargin=-3cm
    \textwidth=17cm
    \textheight=27cm
    
    \hyphenation{trian-gu-lar}
    
    
    \newcommand{\pf}{\vspace{.2in}\hspace{.6cm}{\bf Proof$\,$:\ }}
    
    %\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    
    
    
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \let\wasysymLightning\lightning
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm,nccmath}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage[all]{xy}
    %\usepackage{showkeys} %verETIQUETAS%
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \tikzset{
      symbol/.style={
        draw=none,
        every to/.append style={
          edge node={node [sloped, allow upside down, auto=false]{$#1$}}}
      }}
    % con \[ \] fuerza el centrado y achica
    % con gather no fuerza centrado, solo para ponerle label
    
    \usepackage{xfrac}
    \usepackage{dsfont}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{faktor}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \newenvironment{abstract}{}{}
    \usepackage{abstract}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\newcommand*\quot[2]{{^{\textstyle #1}\big/_{\textstyle #2}}}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    
    
    
    
    %para matriz encerrar entradas
    \usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    
    
    
    %para estilo negrita teorema
    \usepackage{xpatch,amsthm}
    \makeatletter
       \xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} 
    \makeatother
    %para estilo negrita teorema
    
    
    
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{pro}[theorem]{Proposición}
    \newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corolario}
    \newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lema}
    \newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definición}
    \newtheorem{ejem}[theorem]{Ejemplo}
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    
    
    \newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Notación}
    
    \theoremstyle{remark}
    \newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observación}
    
    
    
    \DeclareMathOperator{\nul}{nul}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\defe}{def}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\ind}{ind}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\ase}{ascenso}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\dese}{descenso}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Inv}{Inv}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\inicial}{In}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\final}{Fin}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\spaan}{span}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\spe}{sp}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\ida}{I}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sop}{sop}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sym}{Sym}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{Coker}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proy}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\singa}{singsop}
    
    
    
    % aqui definimos el encabezado de las paginas pares e impares.
    \rhead[\thesection.]{\thesection.}
    \chead[]{}
    \lhead[]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    
    % aqui definimos el pie de pagina de las paginas pares e impares.
    \lfoot[Regularidad elíptica]{Regularidad elíptica}
    \cfoot[]{}
    \rfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    
    % aqui definimos el encabezado y pie de pagina de la pagina inicial de un capitulo.
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    
    %para eliminar encabesado y pie pagina, una pagina limpia
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    
    
    
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
    
    \title{\textsc{something} \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \textbf{something} \\ 
    \vspace*{2cm}
    something \\
    something \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    something \\
    something \\
    something \\
    something \\
    \date{something}}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \selectlanguage{spanish} 
    \begin{abstract}
    Here is the spanish abstract
    \end{abstract}
    \selectlanguage{english} 
    \begin{abstract}
   Here is the english abstract
    \end{abstract}
    \selectlanguage{spanish} 
    
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Introducción}


\chapter{something}\label{something cap}
\section{something}\label{something sec}
\rhead[\thesection. something]{\thesection. something}

\end{document}
```

I solved blank pages using `\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage` but both abstracts are still on different pages.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the [`abstract` package](//ctan.org/pkg/abstract). Just define your own `abstract` environment (and in this case on can just pass the abstract title as an argument, for simplicity):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{abstract}{ m }{%
  \begin{center}
    \bfseries #1
  \end{center}
  \medskip\normalfont}{\par}

\title{A title}
\author{An Author}
\date{Some day}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\mbox{}\par\vfill
\selectlanguage{spanish}%
\begin{abstract}{Resumen}
Here is the Spanish abstract. \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\bigskip

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}{Abstract}
Here is the English abstract. \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\vfill\mbox{}\cleardoublepage

\selectlanguage{spanish}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introducción}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

In the above (minimal) document, the two abstracts are vertically centered on the page using `\vfill`, with manual page breaking via `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but now with this have 2 problems, latex enumerates and adds headers to the abstract page and I don't know how to control the width of the abstract, with user abstract i've used \setlength{\absleftindent}{4em}, but with this dont know

Comment: @user89940: [This code](https://pastebin.com/raw/ptL2P82c) updates the `abstract` environment to now accept an optional argument: `\begin{abstract}[<indent>]{<title>}`...`\end{abstract}` (default `<indent>` is set to `4em`). You seem to be setting the header anyway in your original code. Can't you just do the same within the "`abstract` page" yourself?